# How can I clean up this jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

http://jsfiddle.net/fFJqt/6/

There are two things wrong with this:

1. It is not animating smoothly. Is kind of jumps when the animation starts.
2. I want it to move to (20,25), but rather it is moving right 20, and 25 down from the top. I know I can fix this by making the position absolute, but then the image does not start exactly in the center.

I am getting QUITE frustrated with all of this, so any answers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The animating is running smoothly on my notebook (MacBook Pro). Checked it with Google Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I am on my Macbook and I also tested it with those same two browsers... and it is kind of just flashing with the animation.

Comment: If you point instead of top:20px, top 5%, then it doesn't jump. I think there is an issue with animating between percentage to absolute...